# records exist or not based on conditions in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have doubt in sql server

```
Trantable:
empid  | deptid | Projectname  | Transactionid
1      |10      | test         | 1
2      |11      | test1        | 2
2      |10      | jai          | 3
```

2nd table: dimemp ....>  here dimemp is scdtype2 dimension.its all ready done

```
empkey |  empid  | ename    |  flag
1      |   1     | a        |  1
2      |   2     | b        |  1
3      |  -1     | na       |  1
```

3rd table: dimdept------>here dimdept is scdtype2 dimension.implementaion allready done.

```
deptkey  | deptid  | deptname  | flag 
1        | 10      | hr        | 1
2        | 11      | ceo       | 1
3        | -1      | NA        | 1
```

Here I want load trantable data into facttran table with corresponding keys. here transactionid is unique column
to identiy  unique record.

Facttran table structure look like below and factran we need to maintain scd type1 data.

```
empkey  | deptkey    | projectname |transactionid
```

I tried like below  query

```
merge into  facttran target
using (select ISNULL(a.empkey, (select empkey from Dimemp where empid = -1)) empkey,ISNULL(b.deptkey, (select deptkey from dimdept where deptid = -1)) deptkey, c.projectname, c.transactionid
from  trantable c 
left join dimemp a on a.empid=c.empid and a.flag=1
left join dimdept b on b.deptid=c.deptid and b.flag=1)source 
on  target.transactionid=source.transactionid
when not matched
then  insert ([deptkey],[empkey],[projectname],[transactionid])
values(source.deptkey,source.empkey,source.projectname,source.transactionid)
when matched
then  update set target.empkey=source.empkey ,
                 target.deptkey=source.deptkey,
                 target.projectname=source.projectname,
                 target.transactionid=source.transactionid ;
```

then I got output like below

```
Table :facttran
empkey | deptkey    | projectname   |transactionid
1      |  1         |  test         | 1
2      |  2         |  test1        | 2
2      |  1         |  Jai          | 3
```

upto now its working fine.

2nd day in my  trantable few records updated and few records insert in sourc trantable.based on below table data I want update in facttable with corresponding key.
2nd table: dimemp ....>  here dimemp is scdtype2 dimension

```
empkey |  empid  | ename    |  flag
1      |   10    | a        |  0
2      |   11    | b        |  1
3      |   -1    | na       |  1
4      |   10    | aaa      |  1
```

3rd table: dimdept------>here dimdept is scdtype2 dimension.implementaion allready done.

```
deptkey  | deptid  | deptname  | flag 
1        | 10      | hr        | 0
2        | 20      | ceo       | 1
3        | -1      | NA        | 1
4        | 10      |hrdept     | 1
```

Trantable:

```
empid  | deptid | Projectname  | Transactionid
1      |11      | test         | 1   ------record updated in source side here deptid changed from 10 to 11
1      |11      | test123      | 2  -------Here empid changed from empid 2 to 1 and projectname changed test1 to test123
2      |10      | jai          | 3     ------here no records are  not changed
1      |10      | cod          | 4  ----------new rocrd is came
```

based on above trantable.I want facttran table data look like below.

```
Table :facttran
empkey | deptkey    | projectname   |transactionid
1      |  2         |  test         | 1
1      |  2         |  test123      | 2
2      |  1         |  Jai          | 3
4      | 10         |  cod          | 4
```

when I ran 2nd time with same query.I am not able get to expected result.
here mainily source trantable related transactioni id is exist or not in facttran table .if not exist then we need to insert correspondig dimensionkeys with lates flaf=1
values.if we found transactionid exist in fact table then we need to updated existing  dimension corresonding key.
suppose if we take  transactionid=1 records here only chnaged deptid not empid that time we donot need update empid  corresponding lates flag=1 corresondingkey
we need check exisig transaction id is updated each dimension need to check exist or not if not exist latest flag=1 related corresponding key.
if exist we donot need to updated that one.if new reocrds came then we need to insert with latest flag=1 corresponding keys in factran table.

please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server.

Comment: Just as an aside - [be very careful with `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Your statement isn't currently protected from race conditions, for example.

Comment: can you please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in sql server